# Placing the secondary ID name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So the problem I'm having is being able to set a block with the same ID name.

For example `/give Jason_ minecraft:sand`

but what I'm trying to get is red sand[image]

I know that ID Numbers where taken out so I can't use

> /give Jason_ 12:1

According to http://www.minecraftinfo.com/idnamelist.htm red sand's ID name is sand:1, but I use it like this and I receive an error. `/give Jason_ minecraft:sand:1`

There is no such item with this name.

I have also tried `/give Jason_ minecraft:red_sand` and `/give Jason_ minecraft:sand_red`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/give` syntax:

```
/give <player> <id> [Damage] {tag}
```

The secondary data is stored as the "Damage" value:

```
/give @p minecraft:sand 1
```